# Merge many columns in one, maintaining similarity and replacing diferences

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need a query that can merge many columns in just one.

For Example i have these rows for a column:

```
'JOHNNY WALKER KILIAN JOURNET ANNA FROST'
'JOHNNY CUERVO KILIAN JOURNET ANNA FROST'
'JOHNNY WALKER KILIAN JONES ANNA FROST'
'JOHNNY WALKER KILIAN JOURNET EMELIE FROST'
```

then I want to merge all the rows into just one:

```
'JOHNNY CUERVO KILIAN JONES EMELIE FROST'
```

Is it possible to do this?
This is because I´m trying to do a dynamic query, that then conditions are retrieved by from an XML, but i dont know how much conditions I will get from the XML, so I'm trying with a CTE to loop the conditions from the XML and replace the dinamic query.
Finally I'm getting many rows with the query and some of the conditions.. so i need to merge the differences and preserve the similarity.

THe XML is:

```
<ROOT>
  <PARAMETROS>
    <USU_LOGIN>yleon</USU_LOGIN>
    <USU_NOMBREPRIMERO>Yerusha</USU_NOMBREPRIMERO>
    <USU_APELLIDOPRIMERO>Leon</USU_APELLIDOPRIMERO>
    <USU_EMAIL>yleon@email.com.ve</USU_EMAIL>
    <USU_FECHACREACION>20130510</USU_FECHACREACION>
    <USU_CODICIONES1 TIPO="MC" MARCADOR="CONDICIONES1">AND USU_ID=1</USU_CODICIONES1>
    <USU_CODICIONES2 TIPO="MC" MARCADOR="CONDICIONES2">AND USU_ID=2</USU_CODICIONES2>
    <USU_CODICIONES3 TIPO="MC" MARCADOR="CONDICIONES3">AND USU_ID=3</USU_CODICIONES3>
    <USU_CODICIONES4 TIPO="MC" MARCADOR="CONDICIONES4">AND USU_ID=4</USU_CODICIONES4>
    <USU_CODICIONES5 TIPO="MC" MARCADOR="CONDICIONES5">AND USU_ID=5</USU_CODICIONES5>
    <USU_CODICIONES6 TIPO="MC" MARCADOR="CONDICIONES6">AND USU_ID=6</USU_CODICIONES6>        
  </PARAMETROS>
</ROOT>
```

AND MY CODE IS:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML    
DECLARE @QUERY AS VARCHAR(MAX)
--Lectura del XML almacenado en la tabla SESIONESREPORTES  

SET @XML = (SELECT TOP 1 SER_PARAMETROS FROM   SESIONESREPORTES WHERE  REP_ID = 4 AND SER_ID = 9)

SET @QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE 1=1 CONDICIONES1 CONDICIONES2 CONDICIONES3 CONDICIONES4 CONDICIONES5 CONDICIONES6'               

SELECT T.Item.value('data(.)', 'varchar(255)') AS ELEMENTOSMC
        , T.Item.value('data(@MARCADOR)', 'varchar(255)') AS MARCADOR
        , REPLACE(@QUERY,T.Item.value('data(@MARCADOR)', 'varchar(255)'), T.Item.value('data(.)', 'varchar(255)')) AS QUERY2
        , 0 n
FROM   @xml.nodes('/ROOT/PARAMETROS/*') AS T(Item)
WHERE T.Item.value('data(@TIPO)', 'varchar(255)')='MC'
```

Comment: Each of the four queries return at most one row? Also best to come up with a simple example that uses valid syntax rather than this `CONDICIONES1` etc. pseudo code.

Comment: they are just text, don´t see them like a query.. better i'll rewrite the example..

Comment: What is the logic behind the desired result? `WALKER` is represented three times, why is `DAMON` preserved?

Comment: -1 for not giving us any idea of how/why you are getting the desired result.  Do you just want a row at random?

Comment: I'm trying to do a dynamic query, some WHERE conditions are given into an XML, I need to loop the xml and replace every condition of my dynamic query, i'm using a cte table to do this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a better solution, more simple, with minor potential incidents, and faster, was provided by @Alexander Fedorenko, I just adapted for this question:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<ROOT>
  <PARAMETROS>
    <USU_LOGIN>yleon</USU_LOGIN>
    <USU_NOMBREPRIMERO>Yerusha</USU_NOMBREPRIMERO>
    <USU_APELLIDOPRIMERO>Leon</USU_APELLIDOPRIMERO>
    <USU_EMAIL>yleon@email.com.ve</USU_EMAIL>
    <USU_FECHACREACION>20130510</USU_FECHACREACION>
    <USU_CODICIONES1 TIPO="MC" MARCADOR="CONDICIONES1">AND USU_ID=1</USU_CODICIONES1>
    <USU_CODICIONES2 TIPO="MC" MARCADOR="CONDICIONES2">OR USU_ID=2</USU_CODICIONES2>
    <USU_CODICIONES3 TIPO="MC" MARCADOR="CONDICIONES3">OR USU_ID=3</USU_CODICIONES3>
    <USU_CODICIONES4 TIPO="MC" MARCADOR="CONDICIONES4">OR USU_ID=4</USU_CODICIONES4>
    <USU_CODICIONES5 TIPO="MC" MARCADOR="CONDICIONES5">OR USU_ID=5</USU_CODICIONES5>
    <USU_CODICIONES6 TIPO="MC" MARCADOR="CONDICIONES6">OR USU_ID=6</USU_CODICIONES6>        
  </PARAMETROS>
</ROOT>'

DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE 1=1 CONDICIONES1 CONDICIONES2 CONDICIONES3 CONDICIONES4 CONDICIONES5 CONDICIONES6'             

  DECLARE  @dsql nvarchar(max)

  SELECT @dsql = REPLACE(COALESCE(@dsql, @QUERY), 
                         T.Item.value('@MARCADOR', 'varchar(255)'),
                         T.Item.value('data(.)', 'varchar(255)'))         
  FROM   @xml.nodes('/ROOT/PARAMETROS/*') AS T(Item)  
  WHERE T.Item.value('data(@TIPO)', 'varchar(255)')='MC'

PRINT @DSQL
```

[Dynamic query construccion looping conditions from a xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795312/dynamic-query-construccion-looping-conditions-from-a-xml)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a (mostly) XQuery solution:

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml = '<ROOT>
  <PARAMETROS>
    <USU_LOGIN>yleon</USU_LOGIN>
    <USU_NOMBREPRIMERO>Yerusha</USU_NOMBREPRIMERO>
    <USU_APELLIDOPRIMERO>Leon</USU_APELLIDOPRIMERO>
    <USU_EMAIL>yleon@email.com.ve</USU_EMAIL>
    <USU_FECHACREACION>20130510</USU_FECHACREACION>
    <USU_CODICIONES1 TIPO="MC" MARCADOR="CONDICIONES1">AND USU_ID=1</USU_CODICIONES1>
    <USU_CODICIONES2 TIPO="MC" MARCADOR="CONDICIONES2">AND USU_ID=2</USU_CODICIONES2>
    <USU_CODICIONES3 TIPO="MC" MARCADOR="CONDICIONES3">AND USU_ID=3</USU_CODICIONES3>
    <USU_CODICIONES4 TIPO="MC" MARCADOR="CONDICIONES4">AND USU_ID=4</USU_CODICIONES4>
    <USU_CODICIONES5 TIPO="MC" MARCADOR="CONDICIONES5">AND USU_ID=5</USU_CODICIONES5>
    <USU_CODICIONES6 TIPO="MC" MARCADOR="CONDICIONES6">AND USU_ID=6</USU_CODICIONES6>        
  </PARAMETROS>
</ROOT>'

DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @QUERY = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),
    @xml.query('
        "SELECT * FROM CAIN..USUARIOS WHERE 1=1",
        for $cond in /ROOT/PARAMETROS/*[fn:substring(fn:local-name(), 1, 14) = "USU_CODICIONES" and @TIPO="MC"]/text()
            return string($cond)'))

PRINT @QUERY
```

Produces:

```
SELECT * FROM CAIN..USUARIOS WHERE 1=1 AND USU_ID=1 AND USU_ID=2 AND USU_ID=3 AND USU_ID=4 AND USU_ID=5 AND USU_ID=6
```

Comment: yes, but the original query could be no so simple.. it could have many sub-selects and many conditions in where section..

Comment: Ah well - it was worth a try. I don't think MS SQL's xquery implementation is complete enough to do more. It was only out of interest, really - you already have a good SQL solution. :)